# FormData based on form id or name

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a button outside of form data. When i submit the form, i can get the serialize value but not `FormData`. How can i get the FormData?

```js
function submitForm() {
  console.log($('#form1').serialize());
  console.log(new FormData(document.getElementById('form1')));
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="form1" name="form1">
    <input type="firstname" value="First Name" name="firstname">
    <input type="lastname" value="Last Name" name="lastname">
</form>
<button onclick="submitForm()">Submit</button>
```

Comment: @nnnnnn edited back

Answer (score 11, accepted):

From the [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData/FormData)...

> ## Syntax
>
> ```
> var formData = new FormData(form)
> ```
>
> ### Parameters
>
> **form**
>   An HTML `<form>` element — when specified, the `FormData` object will be populated with the form's current keys/values using the name property of each element for the keys and their submitted value for the values. It will also encode file input content.

You are passing a `jQuery` object, not a form element. Instead, try

```
console.log(new FormData(document.getElementById('form1'))) // by id
```

or

```
console.log(new FormData(document.forms.form1)) // by name
```

or if you still like jQuery

```
console.log(new FormData($('#form1')[0]))
```

Comment: I have edited the code based on your recommendation and it's still the same.

Comment: @stackdisplay can you actually look closely at what you're doing there. It should be obvious what the mistake is

Comment: I have remove the duplicated `new FormData()` but still it same

Comment: What **exactly** do you expect to see? When I run your snippet, I see the `FormData` serialized to the console

Comment: @stackdisplay I suggest you take a look at the `FormData` API if you want to get data back out of it

Comment: I see some value like { append: function() { ... }, delete: function() { ... } } is that what I am suppose to get? I am expecting a key value pair ?

Comment: Yes, that's how it looks in the console